301 правило для главной страницы сайта, на случай GET параметров
То ли боты, толи кто другой. Постоянно, посещают главную страницу сайта с get параметрами.
Возможно ли это поправить посредством htaccess
Если открыта главная страница сайта, а в url есть get параметры. Как выполнить 301 перенаправление, на туже главную страницу, но уже без get?

Прочёл в другой статье на этом же форуме - Оказывается, Апач при POST-запросе на URL папки без конечного слеша, перенаправляет на URL со слешем и при этом запрос трансформируется в GET. Если же слеш поставить, то эффект пропадает.

Если помогло, поставьте ему стрелочку вверх - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121770/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-post-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-get

Вот код в htaccess на вставку слэша в конце - RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
